# How can I convert a Python dictionary's values to data in a Pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, series

I'm trying to write a function for a Geography class (of a CSV data parser program) that converts cities listed in a Pandas Series ( called Cities ) to city ID's.

The Pandas Series would be something along the lines of `df['Cities'] = 'New York'`.

For example, New York has a city_id of 1212. I set up a dictionary from the 2 Series containing the cities and city ID's, so a city_dict would have something like `city_dict = {New York:1212}`.

I tried then to match the keys of city_dict to the cities in  Cities, and then replace the cities in Cities with the city_id. So, in city_dict, if the key 'New York' matches with the string 'New York' in Cities, I would replace 'New York' in Cities with '1212' ( also the values in city_dict is a string, but numerical ).

How can I replace data ( such as the name of a city) in Cities with a value in city_dict ( the value being the city's city_id )?

I thought that I could simply check in a 'if in' statement if the key of city_dict matches the data in Cities, the Pandas Series. Couldn't do that since dict_keys where unhashable. Also `replace()` ( as in the replace the data in the Series with city_dicts values ) wouldn't work since dictionaries in Python don't work with `replace()`.

Here is the basis for my function:

````py
def coding(file, file2):
     list1 = []
     list2 = []
     df = pd.read_csv(file, names=columns, header=None, encoding='utf-8')
     df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, names=codes_columns,header=None, encoding='utf-8')
     dfCity = df['Cities']
     df2id = df2['city_id']
     df2city = df2['City']
     df2id = (df2id) 
     df2city = (df2city) # same as above
     city_dict = dict(zip(df2city,df2id))
     keys = city_dict.keys() 
     keyss = str(list(keys)) 
     strnewdict = str(newdict)
     strkeys = str(keys)
     strdf2id = str(df2id)
     strvalue = str(city_dict.values())
     if dfCity.str.contains('UNKNOWN').any():
           dfCity = dfCity.replace('UNKNOWN','')

     for _ in range(1):
         if dfCity.str.contains(keyss).any():
                 dfCity.replace(keyss,df2id)```
````

I thought of wrapping city_dict around a str, and then using

```
if Cities.str.contains(keyss).any():
(Keyss being the stringfied keys of city_dict)
But that wasn't useful either 
The ultimate goal is to replace the cities with their city_id's and append them to a list, and overwrite the dfCity Series in a new file
```

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Dict to Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(YOURDICT, orient='index')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? How would making another dataframe help me to match and replace elements of a Series?